# Exchange Server not syncing over Outlook Anywhere correctly

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-anywhere

Not sure of the best way of explaining this but I'll give it my best:

We're running Exchange Server 2010 and the mail clients are Outlook 2007. One of my users, when at the office and connected to Exchange over the LAN, will read some mail, delete others, etc. Usual stuff.

When that user goes home he will check his mail (also with Outlook 2007), this time connected via Outlook Anywhere. Some (not all) of the messages he marked as read are unread. Some of the deleted messages return. And the weirdest thing is he has more mail than he did at the office.

For example, his Inbox over Outlook Anywhere has 550 messages, but at the office there are only 520.

He says this has been happening for a few weeks and is getting progressively worse with the number of messages affected.

I have a number of users that connect at the office and also via Outlook Anywhere from home and he is the only one experiencing this behavior.

I'm quite stumped and would appreciate any guidance. Please let me know if I can provide any more specific information to help diagnose this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ctr-right-click on the outlook systray icon to get a copy of the connection status screen on both computers to compare.  I've never heard of this issue either.  I wasn't aware that OA had a sync schedule... thought it was always-up-to-date since it's MAPI over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect he's got his office Outlook set to sync to Exchange on a defined schedule, say, once every 10 minutes.

Then, he does a bunch of mailbox cleanup right before leaving for the day, and closes Outlook before it syncs.

Confirm that it's not an Outlook Anywhere issue by having him check OWA when he's at home.